# Book with glowing green liquid that keeps injured teenage girl alive

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a book in middle school a few years ago about two teenagers who take a boat trip. The girl is a bit of a daredevil, so she goes for a swim. The boy stays on the boat, and sees another boat that isn't paying attention, which hits his unsuspecting friend. She doesn't appear above water for a while and he gets worried. When she does appear, she's pretending he saw things and she's calm and seemingly isn't even hurt.

Later, she becomes weak again and finally tells him about the glowing green liquid she found in a cave that saved her life. Her cuts are back and so he takes her to the green water in the cave. They bottle it up so he can run some tests and so she can have it with her.

Then some important people get involved (I can't remember what tipped them off); they threaten him but he protects her. She is getting closer to death as the green liquid's effect fades. The bottled green liquid loses its glow, so it's no good. Eventually, they are found when he tries hiding her and then he performs a major escape from the hospital with her. He takes her to the cave and while she's happily restoring herself in the glowing green liquid, he traps her in there and leaves.

That's all I remember and it was extremely close to the end of the book by then.

Comment: Roughly when were you in middle school? Do you remember anything about the cover? Was the book geared towards a younger audience? Were there any illustrations?

Comment: I was in middle school a few years ago. Sadly I don't remember anything about the cover. It was one of the stories my teacher had. I don't remember much tho. Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is ["Wild Child"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11061974-wild-child).

Here's the synopsis:

> Briana Fox is the wildest girl in school. She and Kyle have been close for a long time...almost lovers. But Kyle is afraid that if he pushes her, he'll have his heart broken and lose his best friend. When Briana challenges him to a swim across the lake, she's injured in a horrific accident, but she discovers a mysterious substance in an underwater cave that saves her life. What seems to be a magical yet harmless "power drug" invokes superhuman abilities, and Briana soon becomes dependent on it for her very survival. When two government agents learn of the discovery, they will stop at nothing to find the source and turn Briana into a human experiment. Is Kyle willing to risk everything to protect his love?

Reviews of the book emphasize that the liquid is green and glowing, which the synopsis leaves out.

Comment: If this is correct, which it seems so, I searched for `scifi story girl injured boat glowing liquid heals`, which is actually close to what I edited the OP's title to.

Comment: Oh my god that literally sounds like it!!!! Thank you sooo much!!!! (: